# Getting System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException inside RemotingConfiguration.Configure(configFile);

Tags: c#, remote-access, .net-remoting

Inside my code, I use `RemotingConfiguration.Configure(configFile)`

Things work perfectly on a normal network. Whereas Connecting via Microsoft DirectAcess the same API throw and Exception.

```
[Remoting configuration failed with the exception 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ip
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
```

What may be going wrong?

Thank you.